# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'set') discord.js v13

Tags: discord.js, typeerror

I'm making a bot, but there was an error!

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'set')
> at /home/runner/Bot-legal/structures/slas
> h.js:12:30
> at Array.forEach ()
> at module.exports (/home/runner/Bot-legal
> /structures/slash.js:7:29)
> at /home/runner/Bot-legal/index.js:21:39
> at Array.forEach ()
> at Object. (/home/runner/Bot-legal/index.js:20:31)

My code is

```
let slash = []
const { readdirSync } = require("fs");
const ascii = require("ascii-table");
let table = new ascii("Slash Commands");
table.setHeading('Slash Command', ' Load status');
module.exports = (client) => {
    readdirSync("./Slash/").forEach(dir => {
        const commands = readdirSync(`./Slash/${dir}/`).filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"));
        for (let file of commands) {
            let pull = require(`../Slash/${dir}/${file}`);
            if (pull.name) {
                client.slash.set(pull.name, pull);
                slash.push(pull);
                table.addRow(file, '✔️ -> Loaded Slash Command');
            } else {
                table.addRow(file, `❌  -> missing a help.name, or help.name is not a string.`);
                continue;
             }
          }
    });
    console.log(table.toString());
client.on("ready",async ()=> {
    await client.guilds.cache.get('839096342953328691').commands.set(slash);
 })
}
```

Can anyone find the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try, changed a few of the `let`s and made them a `const` since they are never reassigned

```js
const slash = []
const fs = require("fs");
const ascii = require("ascii-table");
const table = new ascii("Slash Commands").setHeading('Slash Command', ' Load status');
module.exports = client => {
    fs.readdirSync("./Slash/").forEach(dir => {
        const commands = fs.readdirSync(`./Slash/${dir}/`).filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"));
        for (const file of commands) {
            const pull = require(`./Slash/${dir}/${file}`); // had too many periods
            if (pull.name) {
                client.commands.set(pull.name, pull);
                slash.push(pull);
                table.addRow(file, '✔️ -> Loaded Slash Command');
            } else {
                table.addRow(file, `❌  -> missing a help.name, or help.name is not a string.`);
                continue;
            }
        }
    });
    console.log(table.toString());
    // Below not needed since they are set above
    // client.on("ready", async () => {
    //  await client.guilds.cache.get('839096342953328691').commands.set(slash);
    // })
}
```